# Unable to get emails from Jenkins ext email plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, jenkins-cli

I set up my job in Jenkins. It works perfectly fine and then it creates a testing report under the "target" folder of my workspace. I am able to access the reports manually, but I haven't been able to send these reports in the body of the email that Jenkins sends. I do get the email from Jenkins but all it contains is the Jenkins logs. A few things I have tried are checking that smtp has been set up properly (able to send email), updating the email ext version, and checking that the Jenkins version is 1.63. A sysadmin email has been set up in configure Jenkins. I am giving the relative path of the HTML report in the body of the email as such:

```
${FILE,path="target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html"} .
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or whether it has something to do with Jenkins. I have tried both absolute and relative paths and neither one works.

This is the exact email I get from Jenkins - Subject and Body of the Email

subject:

> Jenkins build became unstable: Android_Smoke_Test_Cases »
>   somkeTestCases #91

Body:

> See
>   http://localhost:8080/job/Android_Smoke_Test_Cases/com.ABC.Automation.FrameWork$ABC.Automation.FrameWork/91/

And yes HTML text has been selected.
[image]

Comment: Have you set the Content Type of the ext email plugin  to "HTML (text/html)" ? Can you edit your post with the email content you receive currently ?

Comment: @mainframer updated the question with your ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue. I upgraded the Jenkins version to 2.11 and downgraded the ext plugin to 2.25.

Otherwise it just won't send any emails.